# play - "Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0%0:9000"

Tags: playframework, console, localhost

Why kind of address `Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0%0:9000` is? Is it the expected output? Shouldn't it be something like `localhost` printed instead? Except this weird console output everythign works fine. I am running play framework 2.1.1 on OsX.

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: This is the clean new project gerated by:

    `play new my_proj`

Comment: It should be no problem with that. It is IPv6 address for your localhost. So you can access it on `localhost:9000`.

Comment: Can it be changed/set somehow? I'd like my terminal to hyperlink it.

Comment: The url with the ip address is http://[::1]:9000

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That is the IPv6 [unspecified address](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.5.2) which means listen on all addresses, including the localhost address.

Comment: Nope, it's the [unspecified address](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4291#section-2.5.2), meaning that Play binds to all adresses. IPv6 [loopback address](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4291#section-2.5.3) (i.e. `localhost`) is `::1`.

Answer (score 1):

0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0%0 in ipv6 is something like localhost in ipv4 (exact localhost address in ipv6 is ::1 )

you can see the result of your Play app by viewing localhost:9000 in your browser

Comment: That's wrong. It really means *all* addresses, on all network interfaces.

Comment: @cbley you right bro. but I just want to show where they can find their app result without any technical word.